# A wish to see Lord Shiva

Tags: shiva

I have a wish. I want Lord Shiva to appear before me.

Would you please tell me what should I do to attain this?

Comment: Pray to him deeply, he will definitely appear before you. He is your eternal father and father will come before son if son calls him.

Comment: It is said that after chanting Shiva's (any God) name or mantra 13 crore times with earnest devotion, Shiva will appear before you in Physical form. I'm not sure where it was written in scriptures but i saw this on some blogs. You can do that in 4 years with this current busy way of life. All the best

Comment: @AnilKumar No, chanting his name 13 crore times is not required. Sincere devotion is more than enough. In 'Autobiography of a Yogi', Paramahansa Yogananda said that once he prayed very deeply to God, after a few hours, a person came to his door, he was Mahavatar Babaji. In 'Apprenticed to a Himalayan Master', Sri M said that Mahavatar Babaji is none other than Lord Shiva himself.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria that depends on karma too. Buddha got enlightenment within 40 days.( Well whether Buddha was Vishnu or not that's different.) Buddha might have less residual Karma.We cannot believe all those who say they are avatars in this Kaliyuga. What i want to say it depends on Karma and Devotion and Shiva may appear before them immediately  if they have infallible devotion and good karma.

Comment: @AnilKumar Yeah Karma plays a significant role. By the way, who claimed that he is an avatar? As far as I know, Buddha never said he was an incarnation. Ramakrishna Paramahansa got enlightenment in 1 day.

Comment: Time is short and uncertain out of which half of it is passed... I think i need a shaivite guru... Is there any good shaivite master in south India... Because i live in South...

Comment: getting true GURU in this kaliyuga is difficult. Most common answer to "How to get Guru ?" would be just meditate on Lord and Lord will send a Guru for you. Wait for answers or suggestions from Pro members like @sai and swamivishwanada .

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria i didn't mean Buddha but meant Swamis and Babas in India,who claim that they are Avatars of God (generic statement).

Comment: If you want a Jnana answer then: Ask yourself the question, 'Why do you want Lord Shiva to appear before you?' find out the answer to this question. As you go deeper and deeper, only two possible answers will remain 'I want to prove something to someone' or 'I cannot live without seeing Him for I love Him dearly'. If it is the latter, then ask yourself 'Who is Lord Shiva' and this question will give you Real Darshan of Lord Shiva. If it is the former then you will have to continue with the question 'Why do I want to prove'? and you will realize 'I do not need proof, for my Existence is Proof'.

Comment: If you want a Bhakti answer then: Sri Ramakrishna Paramahansa always said that the One who sincerely calls upon the Lord with Love, then God instantly manifests to Him. Suppose there is a mother and there is a child. When the child is playing with toys, the mother does not disturb the child. She goes and takes care of household work. However when the child puts down the toys and cries 'Maa' or 'Amma' or 'Mom' or 'aaa', the mother stops her work (whatever it is) and runs to the child isn't it? Similarly we are caught up in our worldly toys, when we call sincerely The God comes to us sir.

Comment: @AnilKumar Well said sir, traditionally it is believed that only the Guru will find the disciple, not the other way round. Thus the wise ones preach the devotees to pray to God with sincere faith. Then the Guru will call the devotee to Himself. Thank you for the compliment although I must confess I am not a Pro by any means, I am just echoing the words of the saints and the forum experts in Hinduism.SE :).

Comment: @Sai . I think the answer to this Why do you want Lord Shiva to appear before you?' . Its like it's my right to see him...

Comment: @Nisar you should not stop there, please continue questioning, for example, you said 'It is my right'. for example: Why is it your right?  or else ask So what if it is your right? You have so many rights, but you do not try to enforce all of them, however when it comes to this, you are very particular, why? Like this if you keep questioning, then you wil get more clarity. We can continue this discussion in a chat if you want some deep questioning about this. Thanks sir

Comment: You can realize the God, but you can't see any physical appearance, because he does not have one. Otherwise, if you are a yogi, you will see God in every piece of this nature.

Comment: True Devotion is required to meet Lord Shiva

Comment: believe `Shiva`is there everywhere.... & do good things......

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following is an excerpt from Talks with Sri Ramana Maharshi.  May be it is useful to you.

> Miss Umadevi, a Polish lady convert to Hinduism, asked Sri Bhagavan:
>
> I once before told Sri Bhagavan how I had a vision of Siva at about the time of my conversion to Hinduism. A similar experience recurred to me at Courtallam. These visions are momentary. But they are blissful. I want to know how they might be made permanent and continuous. Without Siva there is no life in what I see around me. I am so happy to think of Him. Please tell me how His vision may be everlasting to me.
>
> M.: You speak of a vision of Siva. Vision is always of an object. That implies the existence of a subject. The value of the vision is the same as that of the seer. (That is to say, the nature of the vision is on the same plane as that of the seer.) Appearance implies disappearance also. Whatever appears must also disappear. A vision can never be eternal.
>
> Visions of God have their place below the plane of Self-Realisation.

The crux of that teaching is that **Visions of GOD have a place much below the REALISATION OF GOD.**

The visions of the GOD are our own projections of perceptions of GOD, but not REAL.

---

Even Sri Ramakrishna Paramahamsa had visions of various GODs.  Did he stop there?  No.  He went on with his spiritual practices, till he got the REALISATION.

Coming to the crucial part of it - The visions of God -be it Shiva, Vishnu or Shakti, etc, - will come to a person depending upon the intensity of devotion.

In order to do that one must be prepared to devote maximum amount of his time for praying only, that too **under the guidance of a competent GURU only**.

Please do not be deceived by the life histories of Sri Ramakrishna Paramahamsa, Sri Ramana Maharshi, etc.

They are a class apart.  Their devotion, commitment are not easy to acquire for a common man.

Comment: I strongly disagree. Devotion is not rocket science, there is NO exception in devotion. Sun gives its rays to the most sinful person and the most extraordinary yogi. It knows no discrimination.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria: I never said there is exception in devotion.  I only stated that we should not be swayed away with the life histories of Great persons and immdiately jump into devotion, as it demands commitment.

Comment: I like this point @ChinmaySarupria `The visions of the GOD are our own projections of perceptions of GOD, but not REAL.`

Comment: @srimannarayanakv Yes it is true that visions of God are not the highest thing but what do you mean by one's own projection?

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria: please go through this article http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9024/did-sri-krishna-really-show-viswarupa-darshan-to-arjuna-or-was-it-merely-project

Comment: The path of Bhakti Yoga may require qualifications and discipline, but the path of Sharanagati (described in Gita verse 18.66) requires no qualification or discipline.

Comment: Link to pdf [Talks With Sri Ramana Maharshi Three Volumes In One](http://www.sriramanamaharshi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Talks_Exract.pdf) (3rd February, 1938 | Talk 450)

Comment: Kannappa of Sri Kalahasthi was a commoner  with uncommon depth of innocent and sincere devotion to Shiva.. who like all holy divine spirits are irresistibly  drawn by the intensity of feeling to a devotee.